How is cross correlation used for noise reduction?
Say you use a power divider to split a signal to feed into two channels of an oscilloscope.
And from the captured data say you do
$$ xcorr = IFFT( FFT(CH1(x) * conj(FFT(CH2(x))) )$$
so you now have the cross correlation result xcorr, what are you supposed to do with the cross-correlation to get a noise reduced version of your signal?
If you had like say a digital pulse as the split signal, the xcorr result looks like a triangular pulse now and the peak is where CH1 and CH2 data are most aligned in time. i.e. zero since this is just the same signal split with a power divider fed into the same scope. but it would shift the peak if there was any delay between the two. So i guess that could come in handy if you were just going to take the average of the two signals, but want to align the signals in time first before averaging. That doesn't seem like the right approach though because that doesn't gain you much SNR at all.
How do you infer uncorrelated noise from the xcorr result? i'm thinking of voltage noise, maybe the frequency spectrum of the noise somehow, but is that information even inferrable from the xcorr?
I'm just confused as I keep hearing about using cross-correlation for noise reduction and a cleaner signal result but how are you supposed to go from the xcorr result back to a noise reduced signal, how do I change the triangular xcorr back to actually less noisy square pulse data?
I feel like there are only really two things I can glean from the xcorr result, what time offset does CH1(x) align best with CH2(x) and the bandwidth of the split signal from how wide the triangle pulse in the xcorr is in the middle. But how am I supposed to interpret the xcorr for uncorrelated noise? like am I able to turn it somehow into a filter that I can apply to say CH1(x) to clean it up.
Am I completely misunderstanding what kind of signal or noise is being correlated/uncorrelated?


what are you supposed to do with the cross-correlation to get a noise reduced version of your signal?

the cross-correlation isn't useful for that. It gives you information on how two different signals relate, it doesn't "clean up" one or the other.
By the way, the cross-correlation of a signal with itself is called "autocorrelation".

I'm just confused as I keep hearing about using cross-correlation for noise reduction and a cleaner signal

Sorry, can't help you if you say "I keep hearing about…" but then don't cite any sources. But really, again, cross-correlation is really just the result of combining two signals, not to clean up one or the other.
Autocorrelation especially tells you something about periodicities in your signal, and thus about frequency components. You might want to look up the definition of Power Spectral Density to understand the relationship between autocorrelation and spectrum.

For sources i guess it's a feature on keysight scopes and the fswp from r&s. https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/D9010JITO/infiniium-offline-ezjit-complete-software.html. honestly i would've came to the same conclusion as you had if these features didn't advertise specifically saying cross correlation and noise reduction. I just can't get them to work on either device and the apps engineers are no help.

Under phase noise analysis it says on the keysight page linked it says: using two channels and cross correlation to reduce broadband measurement noise.

@rothran670 are you dealing with high performance clock interval time measurements? That's pretty specific and it would be worth mentioning that in your question itself!

Was trying get more of a general understanding of the relationship rather than just a specific solution. And sort of, i guess for the sake of it let's say i am, it's not exactly a clock but a similar waveform.

but the source you linked to is referring to very specific signals being measured, and of these, very specific properties. There's nothingh "general" about that. there's no "general method" reducing noise there. This is about very specifically reducing the noise in time interval measurements. If you don't care about these, the method is irrelevant to you.

@rothran670, Are you referring to this kind of technique? https://youtu.be/Sf7qiysPFbQ?si=kvdxRbFrlDHMPKT_

@Vincent yes, so in that video it mentions separating correlated and uncorrelated data. I don't understand how that's done with cross-correlation. On the 6th slide at the around the 3 min mark, it shows two signals and then a third that is i think the uncorrelated difference between the two signals. How was that waveform obtained with cross-correlation is what confuses me.
